# Rails association collection using downcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Rails view/form association:

```
<%= f.association :workorder, :collection => Workorder.wonotclosed.order(:description), :label_method => :description, :label => 'Project' %>
```

The issue is the `workorders` are sorted using uppercase first and then lowercase.  I would like it to be case insensitive.

I tried these:

```
:collection => Workorder.wonotclosed.order(LOWER(description))
:collection => Workorder.wonotclosed.order(:description.downcase)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the SQL snippet in as a string:

```
Workorder.wonotclosed.order("LOWER(description)")
```